# Angular ng-grid multiple grids using loop to make it more efficient

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a multiple grids on the page but instead of repeating the code for each grid I'd like to pass the grid name and data into one grid function through loop, this doesn't work for me though. What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
        var grid = [$scope.gridOne,$scope.gridTwo, $scope.gridThree];
        var GridData = ['dataOne','dataTwo', 'dataThree'];
        for(var i =0 ; i < grid.length;i++){
            for(var j =0; j < GridData.length;j++){

                console.log(grid[i]);//i can see this fine in the console
                console.log(GridData[i]);//i can see this fine in the console

                //this below doesn't work
                grid[i] = {
                    data: GridData[i],
                    headerRowHeight: 0,
                    rowHeight: 39,
                    maintainColumnRatios: 4,
                    enableColumnResize : true,
                    enableRowSelection: false,
                    enableHighlighting: true,
                    columnDefs: [
                        {field: 'channel'},
                        {field: 'status', cellTemplate: statusTemplate}
                    ]
            };
           }
        }
```

many thanks for your help

Comment: Can you create a directive for the grid display and include it multiple times on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your GridData it's not well defined. I'd use something like the following

```
var GridData = [{data: 'dataOne'}, {data: 'dataTwo'}, {data: 'dataThree'}];
```

Recall that the data attribute of your ngGrid must be a JSON array, if it is not that will not work but the contents still appear on the console.